# Tradeoff between different formulations of partition of unity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Wikipedia, a [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) of a topological space $X$ is a set $R$ of continuous functions from $X$ to the unit interval $[0,1]$ such that for every point, $x\in X$,

- there is a neighbourhood of $x$ where all but a finite number of the functions of $R$ are $0$, and
- $\;\sum_{\rho\in R} \rho(x) = 1$.

The existence of partitions of unity assumes two distinct forms:

- Given any open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of a space, there exists a partition $\{\rho\}_{i\in I}$ indexed over the same set $I$ such that $\textrm{supp } \rho_i\subset U_i$. Such a partition is said to be subordinate to the open cover $\{U_i\}_i$.
- Given any open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of a space, there exists a partition $\{\rho_j\}_{j\in J}$ indexed over a possibly distinct index set $J$ such that each $\rho_j$ has compact support and for each $j\in J$, $\textrm{supp } \rho_j\subset U_i$ for some $i\in I$.

According to Wikipedia,

> thus one chooses **either** to have the supports indexed by the open cover, **or** compact supports. If the space is compact, then there exist partitions satisfying both requirements.

Would anybody give a simple example (probably in $\mathbb{R}$) showing the difference between the two different choices mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a cover of $\mathbb{R}$ by two open sets, $U_0 = (-\infty,2)$ and $U_1 = (-2,\infty)$ .  Then let 
$$
\rho_0(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x\leq -1 \\
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x & -1 \leq x \leq1 \\
0 & x\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\rho_1(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x\leq -1 \\
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}x & -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\
1 & x\geq 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Then $\{\rho_i\}_{(0,1)}$ is subordinate to $\{U_i\}_{(0,1)}$ in the first sense but not the second.

Note that the cover can't possibly have a partition of unity subordinate to it with compact supports, since $U_0 \setminus U_1$ is not compact, but $\rho_0$ must be $1$ on that set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trivial example. Let $U=\mathbb{R}$. Then $\{U_0\}$ with $U_0=U$ is an open cover of $U$. $\{\rho_0\equiv1\}$ gives a partition with the same index. But there is no way to find $\{\rho_0\}$ with $\textrm{supp }\rho_0\Subset U_0$ since $\rho_0=1$ on $U$.